# Swift : Adding Constraints to UILabel Programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel, ios-autolayout

So I had a break from iOS dev for 4 months and its seems I have forgotten everything.  All I am trying to do is place a Label programmatically at 0,0, size 200,50.  I hear there is a few changes in iOS8 which I don't remember

```
let x : CGFloat = 0.0
let y : CGFloat = 0.0
let width : CGFloat = 200.0
let height : CGFloat = 50.0
self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
self.label.text = "SIMON"
self.label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

self.label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 24)
self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
self.label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.label.layer.masksToBounds = true;
self.label.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width)

heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: height)

leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: x)

topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: y)

self.view.addSubview(self.label)

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leftConstraint,topConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was being dump!

It was the event I was calling it from, not the code.  Moved to viewWillAppear